# Deadlock error occurrd when query mysql in golang, not in query segment but after out of "rows.Next()" loop

Tags: mysql, go, deadlock

when i use golang to query mysql, sometimes i found "deadlock err" in my code.

my question is not "why deadlock occurred", but why deadlock err found in "err = rows.Err()". in my mind, if deadlock occurred, i should get it at "tx.Query"'s return err.

this is demo code, "point 2" is where deadlock error occurred

```golang
func demoFunc(tx *sql.Tx, arg1, arg2 int) ([]outItem, error) {
    var ret []outItem
    var err error
    var rows *sql.Rows

    //xxxLockSql may deadlock, so try again for 3-times
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        //------ point 1
        rows, err = tx.Query(xxxLockSql, arg1, arg2)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }

        log.Printf("[ERROR] xxxLockSql failed, err %s, retry %d", err.Error(), i)
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    }

    //if query xxxLockSql failed up to 3-times, then return
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("[ERROR] xxxLockSql failed, err %s", err.Error())
        return ret, err
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&a1, &a2)
        if err != nil {
            return ret, err
        }

        ret = append(ret, acl)
    }

    //------ point 2
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        // i found deadlock err in this "if" segment.
        // err content is "Error 1213: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction" 
        log.Printf("[ERROR] loop rows failed, err %s", err.Error())
        return ret, err
    }

    return ret, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I cannot be sure about the reason since you did not mention your database driver (and which `sql` package you are using). But I think this is because `sql.Query` is lazy, which means querying and loading the rows is postponed until actual use, i.e., `rows.Next()` - that is why the deadlock error occurs there.

As of why it is out of the loop, it's because that when an error occurs, `rows.Next()` returns false and break the loop.

Comment: my sql driver is "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql", version is "Version 1.3.0 release".